# probability of a collision during people placing calls simultaneously in a city's frequency spectrum

Tags: probability, combinations

The question is like this:

A place divides its frequency spectrum into 100 sets of equal bandwidth. When a user makes
a call, it will be assigned one set of bandwidth randomly. There will be a collision when two or more users use the same set of bandwidth. When 10 people are placing calls at the same time, what is the
probability that a collision occurs?

My approach is like this:

1-[(100C10)/(100^10)]

The 100C10 is going to find the combination of 10 users using different bandwidth within the 100 sets if bandwidth. The 100^10 is all the possible way that 10 users may be assigned to among those 100 sets bandwidth, which may be repeated. So I use 1 to minus it to find out the probability of a collision occurs.

I am not sure about my approach, any hints will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In future, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  You'll get a lot better response if your questions are easy to read.  Your answer is not correct.  Try your approach for small numbers.  Suppose there are $3$ bandwidths and $3$ users.

Comment: I am new to this great platform, thank you for your hint!